# Get DNID in php agi

Tags: php, asterisk, agi

How to get DNID (the number that end user dialled to get to my asterisk server) to my php agi script? I tried

```
$agi->get_fullvariable("DNID"); 
$agi->get_fullvariable("${DNID}");
$agi->get_fullvariable("${CALLERID(dnid)}");
$agi->get_fullvariable("{CALLERID(dnid)}");
```

but i did not get a value. Also can anyone give the proper syntax/method to read an asterisk variable from php agi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out a method. Asterisk passes some data to the agi script, which can be seen by running

```
agi set debug on
```

in asterisk cli. If you are using the phpagi library, then

```
$agi->request['agi_dnid']
```

will hold the dialled number or the number which the caller dialled to get to our asterisk server.

Comment: ${CALLERID(dnid)} - this have be working. but agiphp have no get_fullvariable method, so you need patch it.

Comment: I saw get_fullvariable() method in http://phpagi.sourceforge.net/phpagi22/api-docs/.

Comment: In most phpagi i ever see there was no such function. Maybe they added in latest code. For sure you can easly add it in your phpagi.php file. It is simple rewrite.

Comment: I was looking for an answer for perl and got here so, if perl is your scripting language:

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer for perl and got here so if perl is your scripting language:

```
my %input = $AGI->ReadParse();
my $dnid = $input{"dnid"};
```